# Fancybox Modal Window changing layout in background

Tags: css, debugging, layout, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

So, in my website, every time I click on a thumbnail a Bootstrap modal window is launched as it is supposed to, but with a small bug ... all the layout in the background (except the footer) tilts to the right about 20px. When the modal window is closed the layout shifts back to place.

Can someone help me solve this issue or at least give some hints on what can be causing this?

Comment: Just tested in chrome on mac, no noticeable issues.

Comment: I saw it with Firefox on the Mac... the header moves to the right when clicking the thumbnail.

Comment: yes ... in a first approach only the header shifts ... but if you click the contact link (right hand corner), press submit without filling the form and then press again in a thumbnail, all the layout (except footer) will shift to the right =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/). It's setting the class `fancybox-lock` on the `body` tag and adds `margin-right: 15px;` inline to it.

```
<body class="fancybox-lock" style="margin-right: 15px;">
```

Here's the style:

```
.fancybox-lock {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You can notice the affected parts of the page when clicking the elements if you use Firebug on Firefox for example.

---

This is something that must happen. Note that when there's no `fancybox`, the page has scroll-bars. This pushes the content to the left to accommodate the scroll-bars. When a thumbnail is clicked, `fancybox` acts and removes the scroll-bars from the page, see the `overflow:hidden` and the page content just moves to right to that space that before was being used by the scroll-bars.

Comment: I've commented that css line in fancybox-lock and now the main content shifts to the left and the header stays in place. An extra empty scrollbar now appears on the right when modal is triggered.=/ can you give further suggestions?

Comment: You must remove that style in the body tag. `margin-right: 15px` is the culprit.

Comment: You can also look here for a definitive solution: https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/360

Comment: as you said that margin is being added by fancybox-lock through the overflow: hidden; so i'm not being able to take the margin out without removing the fancybox-lock style. any ideas on how to overcome this issue? by compensation or something like that?

Comment: Thanks Laniel ... I've found some hints on fancyapps github you pointed me. I'm still with some issues (conflicts between Fancybox modal and Bootstrap's alert). images in modals are getting pretty messed up after inputing Bootstrap Alerts. The hole is deeper than it looked. I'll post further developments.

Comment: Yes henser... by the way: Bootstrap has Modals too: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals You can adapt it to your liking... :)

Answer (score 0):

find these classes in fancybox and make sure the contents below match

```
.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
overflow-y: none;   
}
```

and this

```
.fancybox-overlay {
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
display: none;
z-index: 8010;
background: url('fancybox_overlay.png');
}
```

Comment: tried it but didn't see any change.
changing the following solved it:

fancybox-lock{
overflow:visible !important;
margin-right:0px !important;
}

still notice some minor issues: scrollbar appears depending on displayed content in modal.